# Building iOS app for iPhone works from xCode but not from command line (xcodebuild)

Tags: xcode, ios, hudson, provisioning, xcodebuild

I am currently trying to streamline our build and release process with an automated build which runs on an OSX server machine , a MacMini running OSX 10.6.7 with xCode 4.0.1 and iOS SDK 4.3 installed (latest release from Apple). 
I have followed [Mike Nachbaur's](http://nachbaur.com/blog/how-to-automate-your-iphone-app-builds-with-hudson) excellent guide and it feels like I'm almost there but I still have one final obstacle to overcome.

So. We have our app which build fine on:

a) My laptop from within xCode

b) My laptop from command line with xcodebuild

c) the build machine from within xCode

BUT it does not work on

d) the build machine from the command line with xcodebuild.

Here is the end of the console output:

```
CreateUniversalBinary build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/CallControl normal "armv6 armv7"
    cd /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/tools/jdk6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/lipo -create /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol/build/Callcontrol.build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.build/Objects-normal/armv6/CallControl /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol/build/Callcontrol.build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CallControl -output /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/CallControl

GenerateDSYMFile build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app.dSYM build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/CallControl
    cd /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/tools/jdk6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/CallControl -o /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app.dSYM
ProcessProductPackaging "/Users/ainutveckling/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/F792F2E5-45DB-43C7-969C-6012C59BF778.mobileprovision" build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/embedded.mobileprovision
    cd /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/tools/jdk6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> "/Users/ainutveckling/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/F792F2E5-45DB-43C7-969C-6012C59BF778.mobileprovision" -o /Users/ainutveckling/Jenkins/workspace/CallControl_iPhoneContiousBuild/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/embedded.mobileprovision

** BUILD FAILED **

+ failed build
+ echo 'Failed: build'
Failed: build
+ exit 1
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

On my machine, it looks almost the same:

```
GenerateDSYMFile build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app.dSYM build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/CallControl
    cd /Users/anders/Utveckling/CallControl/iphone/totala_samtalslistan/Callcontrol
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/anders/Utveckling/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/Users/anders/Utveckling/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:"
    /Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/anders/Utveckling/CallControl/iphone/totala_samtalslistan/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/CallControl -o /Users/anders/Utveckling/CallControl/iphone/totala_samtalslistan/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app.dSYM

ProcessProductPackaging "/Users/anders/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/F792F2E5-45DB-43C7-969C-6012C59BF778.mobileprovision" build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/embedded.mobileprovision
    cd /Users/anders/Utveckling/CallControl/iphone/totala_samtalslistan/Callcontrol
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/anders/Utveckling/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/Users/anders/Utveckling/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:"
    <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> "/Users/anders/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/F792F2E5-45DB-43C7-969C-6012C59BF778.mobileprovision" -o /Users/anders/Utveckling/CallControl/iphone/totala_samtalslistan/Callcontrol/build/Distribution-iphoneos/CallControl.app/embedded.mobileprovision

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

But success... 
It does not matter if I start the build directly from the command line on the build machine or if it is started by Hudson, same result.
The certificate pointed out above seems to be in place.

I'm almost ready to give up on this, so I would very much appreciate any help to shed some light upon the matter!

Best regards,
Anders

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I seem to be hitting the same error.

Comment: No, I used the old Swedish device "It is never too late to give up" and, emm, gave up. 
I might give it some more time later, but not at the moment. Interesting to see someone else having the same problem here though. Should you find anything, I would VERY much appreciate a comment here.

Comment: Try unlocking your keychain.  I think that's what I did to solve this (if it is indeed the same error).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Have tried that now, didn't work though :-( 
I suppose I will try to reinstall "everything" from scratch as a last desperate move...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the exact error that you showed above on my build machine after updating to a new distribution certificate and provisioning profile.  After the ProcessProductPackaging step, it would just display the ** BUILD FAILED ** message.

However, when running the build manually on the build machine, I encountered the KeyChain permission dialog.  Hitting "Allow Always" fixed the problem.

That in addition to unlocking in the build script:

```
security unlock -p $PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your script:

`security list-keychains -s $KEYCHAINFILE`

This has fixed the issue for me.